# Ploting Confidence interval from only mean and standard deviation

Tags: matlab, statistics, confidence-interval

I am trying to plot confidence interval from mean and standard deviation (std) of the data. Here is the piece of code I wrote:

```
 MeanA=1.876; %mean of A
 STDA=0.018; % std of A
MeanB=1.821;
STDB=0.039;

MeanC=1.735;
 STDC=0.023;
 MeanD=1.667;
STDD=0.039;
 Y = [MeanA MeanB ;
       MeanC MeanD ];     
errY= [STDA STDB;
         STDC   STDC ];
```

If I plot the normal distribution then their cofidence inteval seems to overlap

```
 alpha = 0.05;          % significance level


for tt=1:length(Y)
figure
mu = Y(tt,1);               % mean
 sigma = errY(tt,1);  
cutoff1n = norminv(alpha, mu, sigma);
cutoff2n = norminv(1-alpha, mu, sigma);
 xn = [linspace(mu-4*sigma,cutoff1n), ...
linspace(cutoff1n,cutoff2n), ...
linspace(cutoff2n,mu+4*sigma)];
yn = normpdf(xn, mu, sigma);
plot(xn,yn)
mu = Y(tt,2);               % mean
sigma = errY(tt,2);  
cutoff1 = norminv(alpha, mu, sigma);
cutoff2 = norminv(1-alpha, mu, sigma);
x = [linspace(mu-4*sigma,cutoff1), ...
linspace(cutoff1,cutoff2), ...
linspace(cutoff2,mu+4*sigma)];
y = normpdf(x, mu, sigma);
hold on, plot(x,y)
plot(x,y,'r-',xn,yn,'g-' , 'LineWidth',3) 
set(gca,'Fontsize', 32)
if tt==1
hleg1=legend('A', 'B');
title('study1')
elseif tt==2
hleg1=legend('C', 'D');
title('Study2') 
end
 set(hleg1,'Location','NorthEastoutside')
 set(gca,'Fontsize',22)
 xlo = [x(x<=cutoff1) cutoff1];
 ylo = [y(x<=cutoff1) 0];
 patch(xlo, ylo, 'r')
 xhi = [cutoff2 x(x>=cutoff2)];
 yhi = [0 y(x>=cutoff2)];
 patch(xhi, yhi, 'r')
 xlon = [xn(xn<=cutoff1n) cutoff1n];
 ylon = [yn(xn<=cutoff1n) 0];
  patch(xlon, ylon, 'g') 
  xhin = [cutoff2n xn(xn>=cutoff2n)];
  yhin = [0 yn(xn>=cutoff2n)];
  patch(xhin, yhin, 'g')
end
```

I obtined plots where there is a overlapping in confidence interval (CI).

[image]

Now I need to plot CI in the form of ;

[image]

Can someone help to plot the CI around mean

%%

I am calculating Ci in following manner:

```
    SE2=errY/sqrt(10);
    CI2n=Y-1.96*(SE2);
    CI2p=Y+1.96*(SE2);
```

Please tell if its right way and if yes how can I plot them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 95% confidence interval on the mean `mu` when the standard deviation `sigma` is known and the sample size is `n` is given by

```
CI = mu +/- 1.96*sigma/sqrt(n)
```

So with `mu = Y` and `sigma = errY`, your computation of the 95% confidence interval is correct for a sample size of `n = 10`.

To plot these values with error bars, try the following using MATLAB's `errorbar` function ([documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html)):

```
n = 10;
SE2=errY/sqrt(n);
for i = 1:size(SE2,1)
    figure
    y = Y(i,:);
    x = 1:length(y);
    e = 1.96*SE2(i,:);
    errorbar(1:length(y),y,e,e,'k.','markersize',18);
    if i == 1
        c = ['A';'B'];
    elseif i == 2
        c = ['C';'D'];
    end
    set(gca,'xtick',x,'xticklabels',c)
end
```

which produces [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17UgC.png) (I want to put the image inline, but lack sufficient rep).

You may notice that the confidence intervals do not appear to overlap. However, we can obtain the result in the density plots by setting `n = 1`, which means `CI = mu +/- 1.96*sigma`. I would post a second image, but I need more rep!